# How to run a graph algorithm concurrently in Java using multi-core parallelism

Tags: concurrency, java-8, executorservice, multicore, java.util.concurrent

I want to run an algorithm on large graphs concurrently, using multi-core parallelism. I have been working on it for a while, but haven't been able to come up with a good solution.

This is the naive algorithm:

```
W - a very large number
double weight = 0

while(weight < W)

    - v : get_random_node_from(Graph)

    - weight += calculate(v)
```

- I looked into fork-and-join, but can't figure out a way to divide this problem into smaller subproblems.
- Then I tried using Java 8 streams, for which I need to create a lambda expression. When I tried doing something like this:

`double weight = 0 
Callable<Object> task = () -> {
    can not update weight here, as it needs to be final 
}`

My question is, is it possible to update a variable like `weight` in a lambda method? Or is there a better way in which this problem can be solved?

The closest I have got is by using `ExecutorService`, but run into the problems of synchronization.

***------------EDIT--------------***

Here is the detailed algorithm:

In a nutshell, what I am trying to do, is traverse a massive graph, perform an operation on randomly selected nodes(as long as weight < W) and update a global structure Index.

**This is taking too long as it doesn't utilize the full power of the CPU.**

Ideally, all threads/processes on multiple cores would perform the operations on the randomly selected nodes, and update the shared **weight** and **Index**.

**Note:** It doesn't matter if different threads pick up the same node, as it's random without replacement.

Algorithm:

function Serial () {

```
List<List<Integer>> I (shared data structure which I want to update)
double weight

//// Task which I want to parallelize

while(weight < W) {

    v : get_random_node_from(Graph)

    bfs(v, affected_nodes) ...// this will fill up affected_nodes by v

    foreach(affected_node in affected_nodes) {

         // update I related to affected_node
         // and do other computation
    }

    weight += affected_nodes.size()

}

///////// Parallelization ends here

use_index(I) // I is passed now to some other method(not important) to get further results

}
```

The important thing is, all threads update the same `I` and `weight`.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish - if it's to calculate the weight of the entire graph, using Java streams, you would just have each element of the stream be a node of the graph, use map to map it to the weight, then sum the stream. That should be parellizable as well.

Comment: Let `weight < W`. You start several `calculate(v)`, but after the first `weight += calculate(v)` `weight` becomes `>=W`.
Should other calculation be cancelled, or they can finish their work?
If they can finish their work, can and should they add their results to `weight`?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Whenever `weight > W` all the processes should stop. I  will edit the question to add more details.

Comment: `Callable` to pass to executor need not to be a lambda. It can be of any type that implements `Callable` and so can access to whatever information.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I already tried that, and ran into the synchronization issues(possibly) and get invalidOperationExceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could wrap that `weight` into an array of a single element, it's sort of a know trick for this kind of stuff; even done internally by java, like this:

```
weight[0] = weight[0] + calculate(v);
```

But there are problems with this, since you are going to run it in parallel. You will not get the result you want since `weight[0]` is not thread-safe. And you could use some sort of synchronization, but java already has a great solution for that : `DoubleAdder` that scales far better in contended environments (and multiple cpus).

A trivial and small example:

```
DoubleAdder weight = new DoubleAdder();

private static int calculate(int v) {
    return v + 1;
}


Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(x -> {
                int y = calculate(x);
                weight.add(y);
            });

System.out.println(weight); // 54
```

Then there is the problem of the randomizer that you are going to choose for this: `get_random_node_from(Graph)`. You need to get a random `Node` indeed, but at the same time you need to *get all of them exactly once*. 
But you might not need it if you can `flatten` all the nodes into a single `List` let's say.

The problem here is that Graphs are usually traversed in a recursive way, you don't know the exact size of it:

```
while(parent.hasChildren) {
     traverse children and so on...
}
```

This will parallelize bad under Streams, you can look yourself at `Spliterators#spliteratorUnknownSize`. It will grow arithmetically from `1024`; that's why my suggestion of flattening the Nodes into a single List, with known size; that will parallelize much better.